# Why does my Rstudio always show "Unknown layout"?

Tags: r, rstudio, igraph, arules

Here is an example. (I need these four packages so I library them.)

```
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)

data(Groceries)
rules <- apriori(Groceries, parameter=list(support=0.005, confidence=0.5))
subrules2 <- sample(rules, 10)
plot(subrules2, method="graph", control=list(layout=igraph::in_circle()))
```

And the Rstudio shows that

```
> plot(subrules2, method="graph", control=list(layout=igraph::in_circle()))
Error: Unknown layout
```

I do not know what the wrong is since I can perfectly run these codes on R code online website.

Any one can help me? I appreciate it.

PS: Here is an example that these codes were published online and seems it works. So, it's really weird that my RStudio shows errors.

https://rpubs.com/josezuniga/388416

Comment: RStudio has nothing do with that, it's `graphics::plot()` that doesn't know what to do with the layout you are feeding it.

Comment: Isn't this `plot` from `arulesViz`, not base `graphics`? @Phil

Comment: Thank you, Phil, but would you mind trying to edit my codes so that it could run successfully? I've just come across R and am not very good at it yet.@Phil

Comment: Thank you, but could you please help me fix my codes so that they can run successfully? I appreciate it. @r2evans

Comment: 1. what version of igraph are you using?   You can find out by typing `sessionInfo()`     2. Try using `layout=igraph::layout_in_circle` instead.